# Converting dates to date ranges based on specified criteria using R

Tags: r, date, time-series, data-manipulation

The objective of this code is to create a start date and end date for various periods given a speficified criteria.

Current data format:

```
df = seq(as.Date("2018/12/1"), as.Date("2018/12/31"), "day")
dg = c(rep(0,each=7),rep(1, each=20), rep(0,each=4))

data = data.frame(dates=df,status=dg)
```

Desired output: Create both a start date and end date for each period where status=0.

Is there an R function that can extract dates given a specified criteria to produce these desired results?

example data frame:

```
data2 = data.frame(start = c("2018-12-01","2018-12-28"),
        end = c("2018-12-07","2018-12-31"),
        status = rep(0,each=2))
```

Comment: 1) I have added a call to `set.seed()`. 2) With that data, can you edit the question with the expected output?

Comment: I have edited the data to represent a more simplified example.